# I am trying to change the border color of a button in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to change to border color of a button in python tkinter, I've tried putting it in a frame but it does not work:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

l_f = Frame(root, bg="black")
l_f.pack()
l = Button(l_f, text="fdffdfd", bg="white", fg="white")
l.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try adding `padx=10, pady=10` to `l.pack()`

Comment: You can't change the color of the actual border, but you can simulate it by creating a frame with whatever color you want to hold the widget.

Comment: `Button` border is determined by `relief` which can not be changed without changing the overall color of the `Button`. Setting relief to `flat` and wrapping a `frame` around it is an ad hoc solution that will not change the border color.

Answer (score 0):

You packed a `frame`, but didn't set any option of that frame, to give a border effect.

Try: `l_f = Frame(root, highlightbackground = "black", highlightthickness = 2, bd=0)`

---

Also, you can use `LabelFrame` in place of frame, to add border to a button.

```
l_f = LabelFrame(root, bg = "black", bd=2)
```